# Using com component in threads

Tags: c#, com

I am facing a problem with com component.

I have a com component that has a class abc.
now my console application creates multiple threads and each thread creates a new abc object
so, multiple threads are creating and using abc object parallel,
**but com is processing calls in sequence.**

```
ATSServer Svr = new ATSServerLookupClass().lookup("devcoreatd", 1088);
ATSRequest Req = new XMLUtilClass().buildRequest(readFile("Request\\" + FileName + ".xml"));
ATSResponse Res = Svr.submit(Req);
```

this is written in a method that is executed in multiple threads in parallel

ATSSERVER, ATSREQUEST, ATSRESPONSE, XMLUTIL all are classes from COM

Comment: This is rather ambiguous. Please post some code and give more information about the component you are attempting to use.

Comment: Why don't you show the thread creation and instantiating code? That might give better results.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referencing and invoking COM component from an application running in STA (Single Thread Apartment), instantiating object from COM will cause a queueing automatically and your invokations will work i a single thread. Console apps are STA only.

You can refer this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate.aspx

Comment: No, console apps are MTA by default.  No message loop either, required for an STA thread.

Comment: @HansPassant: I have not seen any by default MTA console app.

Comment: i am not using a single com object for all threads, i am creatting com objects in each individual threads, so each thread has its own copy of COM
still the calls are serialized
is it singleton pattern implemente in com?

Comment: @Pankaj: Can you try what is detailed in the link? It might help.